# Using the Pbinom function in r to solve the posterior probability of rolling a dice 6000 times

Tags: r, self-study

I'm a newbie to stats and have been working on a question for about an hour now.

> You are testing dice for a casino to make sure that sixes do not come up more frequently than expected. Because you do not want to manually roll dice all day, you design a machine to roll a die repeatedly and record the number of sixes that come face up. In order to do a Bayesian analysis to test the hypothesis that p = 1/6p versus p = .175p=.175, you set the machine to roll the die 6000 times. When you come back at the end of the day, you discover to your horror that the machine was unable to count higher than 999. The machine says that 999 sixes occurred. Given a prior probability of 0.8 placed on the hypothesis p = 1/6, what is the posterior probability that the die is fair, given the censored data? Hint - to find the probability that at least xx sixes occurred in $n$ trials with proportion pp (which is the likelihood in this problem), use the R command 1 - pbinom(x-1, n, p).

I'm struggling to even know where to begin calculating this. 
I'm not necessary looking for the answer here, but I am looking for help in understanding how ot use the pbinom function in R to calculate this answer.

I was going with 1-pbinom(999-1,6000,0.17) and multiplying this by 0.8 but that's waaayyy off base. Feeling very much lost here. Any help would be really warmly appreciated.

Comment: This is a Bayesian problem with censored data, so you are going to need to do more than just calculate a simple binomial probability.  Since you are doing a Bayesian hypothesis test I would recommend you start by reading about [Bayes factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor).  See if you can use the information in the question to calculate that value.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I appreciate that. Let me have a dig around and see what I can work out here.